# Executing Postgresql function from Python

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have created a function (taken from wiki.postgresql.org) in my db for getting approximate row count.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ais_history.count_estimate(query text)
        RETURNS integer
        LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
        $func$
                DECLARE
                        rec   record;
                        rows  integer;
                BEGIN
                FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN ' || query LOOP
                        rows := substring(rec."QUERY PLAN" FROM ' rows=([[:digit:]]+)');
                        EXIT WHEN rows IS NOT NULL;
                END LOOP;

                RETURN rows;
                END
        $func$;
```

When I use the function from the psql cli, it works fine.

```
db=> SELECT count_estimate('SELECT * FROM schema.table_name');
 count_estimate
----------------
              4
(1 row)
```

However, when I run it from Python, using either SQLalchemy core or psycopg2, it gives an error.

```
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT count_estimate('SELECT * FROM schema.table_name');")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Error output

```
UndefinedFunction                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [91], in <cell line: 8>()
      5 conn.autocommit = True
      6 cursor = conn.cursor()
----> 8 cursor.execute("SELECT count_estimate('SELECT * FROM schema.table_name');")
     10 conn.commit()
     11 conn.close()

UndefinedFunction: function count_estimate(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT count_estimate('SELECT * FROM schema.table_name...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I run the raw sql to get the function output?

Comment: Either put ais_history in your search_path, or fully qualify the function call with the schema.

Comment: You are not getting as far as output. The error is telling you the problem ' No function matches the given name and argument types.' So either 1) You are not connected to the correct database in the Python case. 2) Or you have a [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)  issue.

Comment: I have tried with explicit schema and have also checked it is in the search path. In psql cli, I am using the same username and have checked search path to confirm. I think the problem is not the function name, it is the argument type. Passing the sql statement as a text string is what is causing the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The sql string is not the issue.  Are you sure you are connecting to correct database?  Check the Postgres log to verify. FYI, `conn.autocommit = True` and `conn.commit()` are redundant. Also since this a simple select commit is not going to do anything anyway.