# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function ... does not exist. Cannot call functions installed via an extension from psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to execute a function which comes from an extension (`postgis`) with `psycopg2`.

```
import psycopg2

SCHEMAS = ["a", "b", "c", ...]
FROM_TABLES = ["foo","bar", ...]

for schema in SCHEMAS:    
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host='localhost',
        database='world',
        user="postgres",
        password="postgres",
        port=5432,
        options=f"-c search_path={schema}"
    )

    for i, table in enumerate(FROM_TABLES):
        with conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                # this works!
                cursor.execute(f"""
                    SELECT * FROM {table} LIMIT 10"""
                )
                    

                # this throws an error
                cursor.execute(f"""
                    SELECT public.ST_Centroid(geom) AS geom, way_id, osm_type, name FROM {table};"""
                )
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This gives me

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function public.st_centroid(public.geometry) does not exist
> LINE 3:     SELECT public.ST_Centroid(geom) AS geom, way_id, osm_type, name...
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

The extension `postgis` is installe on the `database world` though.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension;
```

[image: extensions postgres]

I am not sure what is causing the problem. On my old machine it worked. I have the feeling this might be a privilges/permission problem sine the new Mac OS is rather strict about this. When I try to run the postgis function in `pgAdmin`, it works without a problem... This problem does not only occur with `postgis`, but with other extensions too. I tried already this

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
```

and checking the privileges

```
SELECT DISTINCT privilege_type FROM information_schema.usage_privileges ;
```

which returned

> privilege_type : USAGE

But it is still not working. Any ideas what might be the problem?

---

***Edit**

This is the result of `\df ST_Centroid;` in `psql`.

```
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)
```

The result of `show search_path;` in `psql`.

```
   search_path
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)
```

Result for `\df *.ST_Centroid;` in `psql`.

```
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)
```

Result for `\dn;` in `psql`.

```
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner
--------+----------
 public | postgres
(1 row)
```

This is the result of `\dx`

```
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(1 row)
```

Comment: 1) What version of Postgres? 2) Is `ST_Centroid()` actually in the `public` schema?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it is `PostgreSQL 14.4 on aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9), 64-bit`. How would I check `2)`?

Comment: In `psql` do `\df ST_Centroid`. It will show you the schema. While you are there also do: `show search_path;`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I edited my question with the results

Comment: 1) Do not use images for textual data, copy and paste as text. 2) In `psql` do `\df *.ST_Centroid` 3) In `psql` do `\dn`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for sticking with me. I edited my Q accordingly.

Comment: Big oops on my part. I was not paying attention to the name. Try `\df  *."ST_Centroid"`. The mixed case name needs to be double quoted to preserve the case.  And I missed it in the error also: `... public.st_centroid...`. Without the quoting the name is being down cased to `st_centroid()` which in fact does not exist. So in the python code: `SELECT public."ST_Centroid"(geom)...`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Adding the double quotes `""` does not solve it. This would have suprised me, because, as I wrote, on my old machine it worked like this. Switching to the new machine made the script crash. And I assume this is a permission problem... Maybe that the user I am executing the script with has no permission to see, where the extensions are saved? Or something with the `searchPath`? `\df  *."ST_Centroid"` yields an empty table too by the way.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Basically, it is the same problem as here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324386/psycopg2-programmingerror-function-does-not-exist and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73520114/executing-postgresql-function-from-python. But, the proposed solutions in the linked Q's do not work... I checked the `public` schema in pgAdmin for the `ST_Centroid()` function, it is in there (downcasted)

Comment: It  is not a permissions issue. I suspect you are connecting to two different databases. In `psql` do `\dx` to see if `PostGIS` is installed.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added the result to the question

Comment: @AdrianKlaver There seems to be something deeply wrong with my database... In pgAdmin, I cannot select some tables. It tells me that this table does not exist... Yet, others I can select. That is really odd.

Comment: You need to confirm whether you are connecting to the same instance of Postgres when you use pgAdmin as when you use psql. The evidence would say you are not.